# Weird PSU behaviour

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

My HTPC stopped powering up. **NOTHING AT ALL** happens when I press the power button on the case **AND** the power button on the motherboard itself, too.

My first thought was that the ATX PSU, which is not the newest, had died.

I did the paperclip test and the fan came on. Next, I measure the voltage across all the pins in the 24pin plug and the 8pin CPU plug. All the voltages were correct.

So, my next thought was that the motherboard was dead. To confirm this I plugged it to my main machine's PSU and it came on! WTF?

To double check, I then plugged the HTPC's PSU to my main machine and it didn't start or light up anything.

So, clearly the issue is with the HTPC PSU, but I'm very confused as to why I'm measuring all the right voltages on it when it is unplugged, and yet the motherboards don't even light up when it is plugged in!

Can anyone explain this? And if so, is it fixable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you remove the bios battery from the motherboard?

Comment: Hi, Gerard, when I was trying to debug this,  I checked the CMOS battery and it was dead, so I replaced it with a brand new one, but it made no difference... I am assuming that by "bios battery" you mean the CMOS battery.

Comment: Most MB's only have one battery, that's the one I meant. I currently have a MB that every couple of months, refuses to boot, until I remove the battery and put it back.  I would remove as much as possible, see if it boots with only CPU and RAM.  If not, you ask Santa for a new PSU.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage under load is an absolute *£$%^&* to try measure with a standard multimeter.

Most failing but not yet dead power supplies will put out the correct voltages when not under load. As soon as they're under load, that's when they fail to keep up.

This was so much of a nuisance for engineers away on-site at one job I had, that we had load testers built so the guys could just get a simple green/yellow/red light to test by just plugging the PSU to it, rather than juggling loads. These days, you can get hand-held multimeters that will actually load a connection… that only leaves you needing to know what the correct load should be…

PSUs just get "tired" over time. They can usually be fixed, but it's often not worth the cost or effort.

Comment: Thanks, Tetsujin! But would just powering the lights without powering the computer be considered "under load"?

Comment: No. Only powering the entire machine. Also, by its very nature if the machine is running from the PSU you cannot measure the voltage correctly. This is why we had load testers built ;) See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/412098/does-battery-voltage-actually-get-lower-when-connected-to-a-load-or-does-it-jus for a far better explanation than I can give. It's mainly about batteries, but the same rules apply.